# How does this For To loop work in this context

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvmcross

This line of code was written by another dev:

```
bindingSet.Bind(_imageViewLoader).For(i => i.ImageUrl).To(vm => vm.ImageTextImagePath);
```

Some data (this is not an image) also resids within the variable `vm` (vm.text)

But vm does not exist outside of this shorthand loop (which I guess is what this is).

How can I access the data on `vm` outside of the loop?

Comment: There are no `For()` and `To()` methods in C# or .NET. This doesn't even seem to be a loop, it looks like a Fluent databinding API. The `ImageUrl` UI property is bound to the `ImageTextImagePath` data property. Hover over `For` or `To` to find out what library they're from

Comment: Looks like MvvmCross?!

Comment: Are you using MvvmCross? The [Data Binding docs](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding) show exactly this syntax

Comment: It is a Fluent API Pattern, and it is based on `Lambda`. Check this document  [Lambda expressions (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) and for Fluent API, just google it, and you will find a lot of exciting tutorials

Comment: @Mohi Fairly sure both myself and @Panagiotis Kanavos are familiar with the use of fluent APIs and Lambda expresssions, that's not what we're questionning. The `.Bind().For().To()` appears to be specific to some framework.

Comment: Yes, it is mvvmCross. And youre right, its actually not a loop. But I dont know how to extract the data on the vm variable. I do see its content during debug, but cannot access it outside this For().To(). Anyone got any idea?

Comment: @phuzi Fairly sure my comment pointed to one who asked the question ;)

Comment: @Mohi My apologies, I misinterpreted the general nature of the statement. Sorry.